# Multi delete checkbox on button click does not work as required

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a grdiview in which I have added the Multi-delete functionality. Please see the code for your reference:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateAll() {
        var chkselectcount = 0;
        var gridview = document.getElementById('<%= grdTeacherProfile.ClientID %>');
        for (var i = 0; i < gridview.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
            var node = gridview.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];

            if (node != null && node.type == "checkbox" && node.checked) {
                chkselectcount = chkselectcount + 1;
            }
        }
        if (chkselectcount == 0) {
            alert("Please select atleast One CheckBox");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            ConfirmationBox();
        }
    }
    function ConfirmationBox() {
        var result = confirm("Are you sure, you want to delete the Users ?");
        if (result) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Also see the button html:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:return ValidateAll();" />
```

The issue is that,
when I check the checkboxes and Click on delete button, it asks for confirmation. When I click on Cancel it still deletes the row from the `Gridview` as well as `sql table`.

What should I do for the proper working of this. ? Please suggest

Comment: `OnClick="btnDelete_Click"` try removing it.

Comment: @Jai: Its fine, the answer given by Shekar is working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use

```
return ConfirmationBox();
```

instead of

```
ConfirmationBox();
```

So your code becomes

```
function ValidateAll() {
    var chkselectcount = 0;
    var gridview = document.getElementById('<%= grdTeacherProfile.ClientID %>');
    for (var i = 0; i < gridview.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
        var node = gridview.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];

        if (node != null && node.type == "checkbox" && node.checked) {
            chkselectcount = chkselectcount + 1;
        }
    }
    if (chkselectcount == 0) {
        alert("Please select atleast One CheckBox");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return ConfirmationBox();
    }
}
```

You need to remove the `javascript:` from `OnClientClick` you can use `OnClientClick="return ValidateAll();"`

Comment: it is not working, it is still deleting the row. Did you checked my button html code ?

Comment: the button client click seems to be fine. though you can remove `javascript:` and write juse `OnClientClick="return ValidateAll();"`

Comment: yes, that is working now.. please update your answer so that I can mark it.. :) Thanks Shekhar.